# How to write a JPA query with an "order by" clause against a property that may be null

Tags: java, jpa

I have defined a JPA entity "A" with a @ManyToOne relationship to another JPA entity "B".

```
@Entity
class A {

    String name;

    int sortOrder

    @ManyToOne
    B b;

}
```

This reference can be null or it can be populated. Now, I would like to query all the As and sort by B.name. Unfortunately, something like

```
find("order by B.name, sortOrder, name")
```

seems to drop any As such that (A.b = null). What is the best way to write this query?

I want all the As and I want them sorted by their B.name reference if it exists ... lumping all those with no B property together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a left join.

```
select a from A a left join a.b b order by b.name, a.sortOder, a.name
```

or something like that.

Comment: That did it! I didn't know I could use such raw SQL in the JPA block. Thanks!

Comment: @LutherBaker It's not raw SQL, it's JPQL, an integral part of JPA.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches … Sets/Comparators, HQL, Native Sql, @Sort annotations …